# OpenVPN set alias for server

Tags: openvpn

I have made VPN server in my local (home) network, it does run in bridging mode.

Now, I want to configure my notebook to be able to connect to my VPN, but I want it to use server's local lan IP when using my notebook at home and use server's public IP when using my notebook at school/...

**How can I add alias for server address in client configuration?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<connection>
  remote 11.22.33.44 1194 udp
</connection>
<connection>
  remote 10.0.0.1 1194 udp
</connection>
```

[According to documentation:](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage)

> An OpenVPN client will try  each  connection  profile  sequentially
>   until it achieves a successful connection.
>   --remote-random  can be used to initially "scramble" the connection list.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your .bashrc or zshrc.

`alias vpn="sudo sh -c 'nohup openvpn /etc/openvpn/client.ovpn 2>&1 > /dev/null &'"`

Note.
if you are using user/password to auth, you need put it into /etc/openvpn/authfile,

`➜  ~ cat /etc/openvpn/authfile 
xuxiaoping
xuxiaoping@123`
```

then, change /etc/openvpn/client.ovpn as 

`auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/authfile`